# Rescue /usr/bin on Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian, rescue

I accidentally deleted the /usr/bin directory. Using a bootable usb, is it possible to rescue my machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible, but you might be better off re-installing. If you want to try, I would first try to copy enough of `dpkg` to your filesystem that dpkg will run. There are a bunch of files from `dpkg` that are in `/usr/bin/`. Copy those in. For convenience, the list is

```
/usr/bin/dpkg-trigger
/usr/bin/dpkg-deb
/usr/bin/dpkg
/usr/bin/dpkg-query
/usr/bin/dpkg-split
/usr/bin/dpkg-maintscript-helper
/usr/bin/dpkg-divert
/usr/bin/update-alternatives
/usr/bin/dpkg-statoverride
```

Then you can download debs to the system, to, first, reinstall `dpkg`, and then reinstall `apt`. `apt` and `dpkg` don't seem to depend on other stuff in `/usr/bin`, so they might run. Once you have dpkg working, you can get a list of packages you have installed (using, e.g. `dpkg -l`), and then run `apt` to reinstall them. A detailed recipe would be hard without actually trying it.

If you do decide to go that route, post comments here if you run into problems.

Comment: I just ended up reinstalling after copying over as many files as possible with dd. Thanks for the answer, though! When I inevitably screwup again, I'll be back.